# JAVAFX Updating TableView from ListView selection

Tags: listview, tableview, javafx

I'm trying to make the tableview "get" values from an object that  select from a listview without sing buttons, is it possible to have it onMouseClick to get the listView object throught the update from Observers?

```
@FXML
public void onMouseClickLista(ActionEvent e) {
    int x = listaTitulo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    update(listaTitulo.getItems().get(x),null);

}
```

Unfortunately been trying several ways but been having errors on all :(

Answer (score 0):

just add listener to listView selection model

code :

```
listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue arg0, Object oldVal, Object newVal) {

             System.out.println(" Selected value : " + newVal);
                  // newVal is Object so cast it to type supported by your ListView
                 //here update TableView using value you got from selection (newVal) 

        }
    });
```